# Why has my float value from getFloat() become 0.0?

Tags: floating-point, getter-setter, volume, pi, main-method

I'm new on java is there any problem with my coding about float? because it became 0.0 and I didn't understand float much can you explain it? It happen on getFloat

This program to calculate cone volume

```
public class Cone_Volume
{
private int ri, hi, ivol;
private float rf, hf, fvol;

public Cone_Volume()
{

}

public Cone_Volume(int ri, int hi)
{
    this.ri = ri;
    this.hi = hi;
}

public Cone_Volume(float rf, float hf)
{
    this.rf = rf;
    this.hf = hf;
}

public int getInt()
{
    int ivol = (int)((3.142f*(ri*ri)*hi)/3);
    return ivol;
}

public float getFloat()
{
    float fvol = (float)((3.142f*(ri*ri)*hi)/3);
    return fvol;
}

public void Volume_I(int ri, int hi)
{
    this.ri = ri;
    this.hi = hi;
}

public void Volume_F(float rf, float hf)
{
    this.rf = rf;
    this.hf = hf;
}
}
```

this program is for main method for Cone_Volume

```
public class TestConeVol
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Cone_Volume cone1 = new Cone_Volume (5,10);
    Cone_Volume cone2 = new Cone_Volume (3.5f,7.9f);
    Cone_Volume cone3 = new Cone_Volume ();
    Cone_Volume cone4 = new Cone_Volume ();

    cone3.Volume_I (10,30);
    cone4.Volume_F (9.4f,5.8f);

    System.out.println("Volume of cone one : " + cone1.getInt());
    System.out.println("Volume of cone two : " + cone2.getFloat());
    System.out.println("Volume of cone three : " + cone3.getInt());
    System.out.println("Volume of cone four : " + cone4.getFloat());
}
}
```

Output:

```
Volume of cone one : 261

Volume of cone two : 0.0

Volume of cone three : 3141

Volume of cone four : 0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method `getFloat` you mistakenly used `ri` and `hi` instead of `rf` and `hf` (respectively).

The important lesson here is to use meaningful names ;)